# Show Alert on ViewController from external static function

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

I have a signup view controller that calls upon a `Service` class and uses its `static func signUp(...)` to sign someone up to a database.

If signup is unsuccessful, an alert should be displayed via the `showAlert(...)` static method.

However, what is happening is the unsuccessful signup is logged but the alert does not display with my current approach.

`Attempt to present <UIAlertController: xx> on <Yyy:SignUpViewController: ss> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Currently, I am trying to pass the SignUpViewController as a parameter (`vc: UIViewController`) to the static method, then calling `Service.showAlert(on: vc, ...)`.

I also tried incorporating the `showAlert(...)` method inside the `SignUpViewController` class as an `extension UIViewController` instead and calling it from `Service` `signUp()` as `vc.showAlert(...)`. I received the same error as above.

Importantly, I want to reuse the code for database calls from different View Controllers, so I don't want to rewrite the code and place it inside each View Controller. This isn't just for signing up. I want these database calls inside an external class.

Code:

Service class

```
static func signUp(email: String, password: String, vc: UIViewController) {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authResult, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to sign in with error ", error)
                Service.showAlert(on: vc, style: .alert, title: "Sign-in Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            // ...code
        }
        // ...code
}

// other methods

static func showAlert(on: UIViewController, style: UIAlertControllerStyle, title: String?, message: String?, actions: [UIAlertAction] = [UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)], completion: (() -> Swift.Void)? = nil) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: style)
        for action in actions {
            alert.addAction(action)
        }
        on.present(alert, animated: true, completion: completion)
}
```

SignUpViewController class method call

`Service.signUp(email: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, vc: self)`

**Edit:**

If I carry out sign in functionality from within the `SignUpViewController` the alerts are displayed:

```
@IBAction func btnActionLogin(_ sender: Any) {
                    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: self.emailTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!) { (authResult, error) in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("Failed to create new user with error ", error)
                            Service.showAlert(on: self, style: .alert, title: "Account Creation Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
                            return
                        } else {
                        // ... more code
                    }

}
```

**Edit 2:**

My implemented approach was actually fine. It was my execution of switching View Controllers that was in the wrong place! I accidentally switched View Controllers, implying a successful login, even when it wasn't successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot be 100% sure on the solution without looking at the Auth documentaiton, however I imagine that the function`Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password)` executes on a background thread.

The error `Attempt to present <UIAlertController: xx> on <Yyy:SignUpViewController: ss> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!` could be caused because you are calling `Service.showAlert(on: vc, style: .alert, title: "Sign-in Error", message: error.localizedDescription)` from this background thread. The view is most likely no longer on the stack when the background thread executes your command to show an alert to the user.

It is important to run any code the impacts the UI on the main thread.

I recommend you execute the code asynchronously on the main thread by wrapping that line of code with `DispatchQueue.main.async` as follows:

`DispatchQueue.main.async {
    Service.showAlert(on: vc, style: .alert, title: "Sign-in Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
}`

Hopefully this solves the issue. If not report back, and I will try and think of what else is going on.

**Update**: To answer your question regarding the correct approach for displaying an alert:

> "Currently, I am trying to pass the SignUpViewController as a
>   parameter (vc: UIViewController) to the static method, then calling
>   Service.showAlert(on: vc, ...). I don't think this is the correct
>   approach."

I use the same approach of calling a static method. I don't see an issue with this paradigm. The way I typically do this in my projects is as follows:

I created a static method similar to yours that handles presenting an alert on a view controller.

```
/** Easily Create, Customize, and Present an UIAlertController on a UIViewController

 - Parameters:
    - target: The instance of a UIViewController that you would like to present tye UIAlertController upon.
    - title: The `title` for the UIAlertController.
    - message: Optional `message` field for the UIAlertController. nil by default
    - style: The `preferredStyle` for the UIAlertController. UIAlertControllerStyle.alert by default
    - actionList: A list of `UIAlertAction`. If no action is added, `[UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)]` will be added.

 */
func showAlert(target: UIViewController, title: String, message: String? = nil, style: UIAlertControllerStyle = .alert, actionList:[UIAlertAction] = [UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)] ) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: style)
    for action in actionList {
        alert.addAction(action)
    }
    // Check to see if the target viewController current is currently presenting a ViewController
    if target.presentedViewController == nil {
        target.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I then call the function from within my view controller like so: `showAlert(target: self, title: "Error", message: "Some error message")`

Comment: You're right that the auth is carried out in the background but this doesn't affect it as far as I can tell. Correct me if I'm wrong. If I carry out all sign in functionally from within the SignUpViewController and call the Service showAlert from there it works fine and shows alerts. I'll edit the post to demonstrate what I mean.

Comment: I have realised my error. See Edit 2. My approach was fine the whole time. It was a different error. I've accepted your answer as it's similar to what I'm doing.